# Button Text color is not getting changed in android

Tags: android, android-button, textcolor

I m trying the change the colour of text on button (created dynamically); On the first click it is working ,but when clicked again it suppose to change .but the previous colour retains and new clicked button colour changes .Please do suggest where i am doing it wrong .Below is the code i m using.

```
final Button clickedBtn = (Button)ll.getChildAt(position);// ll is my linear layout
 bval = v.getId();//Bval is the button id
 String my = String.valueOf(bval);

 btag = (Integer) v.getTag();

 if(position>29 && position <=59){
  Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position).toString());
  Log.d("previous text is", preText);
  int sum = 30;
  sum = position - sum;      
  position = sum;

  for(int k=0; k< 30; k++){
   if(k!=btag){
    previousBtn.setText(Html
      .fromHtml("<b><font color='#1F383C'><strong><strong><big><big><big>"+ values[k] 
        + "<big><big><big><strong><strong></font><b>"));
    Log.d("value green", String.valueOf(k));
   }
   } 

  clickedBtn.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><font color='#FF9000'><strong><strong><big><big><big>"
   + values[btag] + "<big><big><big><strong><strong></font><b>"));
  Log.d("value orange", String.valueOf(btag));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand your code because I don't know exactly what you want to do, I'm gonna say what I understand and then you can clarify me and I can edit my answer.

You have let's say 3 buttons, when you click one, it gets one color and the other 2 gets other color. So the clicked button gets highlighted, it's that right?

Additionally you are setting button.settag(someValue) which is? (I'm going to assume position)

If so, then you are checking against position > 29 and < 59 but, the cycle (for setting the other's buttons colors) you go from 0 to 30. And you never set those buttons.

So try making the inner FOR from 29 to 59.

If I got all this wrong please tell me to edit my answer.

HIH